# Azure AD: The requested federation realm object does not exist

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

when I try to use SamlAssertion in order to get OAuth2 token which I could use for Graph API Calls (following this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion) I got following issue:

[image]

any idea what this is and how to fix it?

Thanks,
Mirko

Comment: Have look on this discussion : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40210

Comment: Hi. I am currently working exactly like this. Have you found solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth 2.0 SAML bearer assertion flow allows you to request an OAuth access token using a SAML assertion when a client needs to use an existing trust relationship.

A SAML assertion is an XML security token issued by an identity provider and consumed by a service provider.

Seems you are using wrong token endpoint it should be like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Reference:**  [Microsoft identity platform & SAML bearer assertion flow | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion)

**If above one is still not working. You can try the below suggestion as well.**

You cannot use this SAML response. After SSO you can use Auth Code Grant to retrieve access token.The key is session cookie. When you are logging user with SAML you generate a session cookie. After that when Graph API invokes an OAuth flow you use the session cookie to authenticate. Actually, you need 2 apps in https://portal.azure.com/.
One enterprise app for SSO and one in App registrations for OAuth (Auth Code Grant).

**Reference**: [AADSTS50107: Requested federation realm object 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist error is coming while calling the token api with assertion token · Issue #40210 · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40210)

Comment: Is there any documentation for the authorization code workaround...?